# How to pass % in a URL query string?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass a string via HTTP request which has one of the character as `%` in the URL query string.

```
url = url + "?q=" + str + "&block=" + block;  // str contains the '%' character
```

But on the ColdFusion page where I'm sending this information is returning following error:

> Element Q is undefined in URL.

How can I encode the `%` sign in a URL?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should url-encode all the values you are passing as query parameters, but the url-encoding for % is `%25`

**Update**: if you're constructing the query parameters in javascript, you probably want to do:

```
url=url+"?q="+encodeURIComponent(str)+"&block="+encodeURIComponent(block)
```

(Updated again with ZeissS' very helpful suggestion to use `encodeURIComponent` instead of `escape`. See also http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/)

Comment: You should use `encodeURIComponent()`, since you are escaping a single component of the URL.

Answer (score 9):

Pass your string trough the function `encodeURI(...)` it will escape all the special characters not only the %

Comment: Also consider `encodeURIComponent`, as pointed out in Brad G.'s answer below. `encodeURI` does not encode some characters which *should* be encoded in a case like this. One character it does not encode, as a trivial example of why it's potentially bad here, is '&'.

Comment: @pst But if you want to pass parameters in the query string why do want to escape the & which separate the parameters?

Comment: Thanks I returned here to ask tht only bcoz I was getting problems with & .. ;) thank you

Answer (score 4):

%25

http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp

Answer (score 3):

[URLEncodedFormat()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7bdf.html) in ColdFusion

Comment: Thank you for your time. 
Can I use URLEncodedFormat() while I am inserting the data in Oracle database ?

Comment: sure, but you must ask yourself if that's really what you want to do.

Answer (score -2):

We can use URLEncodedFormat() in ColdFusion as well as we can use the below mentioned one.

- encodeURI(...)
- encodeURIComponent

This two also help us to resolve our issue.